# How can we search meaning for a word in html text. when the searched in the input box

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to write a code in which we have to find all the synonyms of the word.
The word has to be written in an input type of a form and on submit lists all the synonyms.

Comment: Can you provide some code showing what you have tried and what specifically you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you would need a thesaurus. The best bet is to use an API to retrieve that somehow. For instance, you could bind the form's `submit` event to a function which fetches data from the [Big Huge Thesaurus](https://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php) and formats that data back into the page.

Answer (score 0):

From your question i understand that you need to display synonyms for a word. for that you need to hit a Dictionary API.

So can you try below link

```
https://www.wordsapi.com/mashape/words/searchWord?when=2018-02-08T04:12:05.603Z&encrypted=8cfdb282e722919bea9907bfeb58bfbbaeb0280936ff94b8
```

in place of **searchWord** you need to put your word.

Then it will return a JSON with meaning and synonyms of that word.

You can refer [this link also.](https://www.wordsapi.com/)